# Why is NodeMCU triggering gpio in reverse when using Lua?

Tags: lua, esp8266, gpio, nodemcu

When using Lua and the `GPIO` module with my `NodeMCU`, my the high and low values are occurring in reverse.

I downloaded my build from NodeMCU custom builds: [Link](https://nodemcu-build.com/)

To turn on the blue LED on the `ESP8266`, normally you set `GPIO` pin 0 to high. What's happening for me is I have to set it to low.

This is what I'm executing in the serial console to light up the blue LED:

```
gpio.write(0, gpio.LOW)
```

If I take this pin and directly connect it to ground, it also lights up the blue LED which I believe is correct.

What's causing my low and high values to be read incorrectly in `NodeMCU`?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal - the on-board LED turns on with a LOW value and turns off with a HIGH value.
I've programmed these both in Lua and Arduino and the on-board LED works the same way.

Try attaching a regular LED to the same pin. You'll notice that it's inverse -- it will turn on with a HIGH value and off with a LOW value.

Comment: You are correct, connecting an LED works as I'd expect. On the other hand, I have a relay connected, and I'm seeing it turn on when `LOW` and off when `HIGH`.

Comment: That's how some relays work. Put to LOW to turn ON. Usually the relay has 3 pins for the mains. VIN, NC, NO. If you want your appliance to turn ON when the pin is HIGH, simply move one of your cables between NC and NO.

Answer (score 1):

HIGH means the pin is set to supply voltage (it is "sourcing" voltage) and LOW means it is set to 0V (it is "sinking" voltage).

Assuming this board is wired like most of them, this is the rough schematic of the LED (note that "0" in gpio.write refers to GPIO16 hardware pin per the [diagram here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/gpio/)):
[Diagram of the GPIO16 pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWCvO.png)

You can see the diode is "pointing" in the direction that current should flow through it for the diode to light, which is "towards" GPIO16. So to get current to flow you need to set GPIO16 to LOW (0V) so there is a voltage difference. Otherwise both sides of the diode are at 3.3V and no current flows.